# Ionic Side Menu not working on mobile devices

Tags: ionic-framework

The Side Menu fails to open initially when the app starts. But after clicking on a text box (*which re-sizes the view port?*) it starts working properly.

Problem is in the drag event, where value of condition
`!e.gesture.srcEvent.defaultPrevented` is coming up false in case of mobile devices.

After removing a condition from ionic source code (from `this.isDraggableTarget` function), it started working correctly.

I would like to know how can I achieve this without changing ionic source code.

Comment: Can you show your  <ion-side-menus> code?

Comment: hi.. did you solve the problem?

Comment: I solved mine yesterday, but thank you anyway. :)